# Will MongoDB overwrite my custom id attributes of my JSON when inserting it into a Collection?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, nosql

Struggling to understand MongoDBs handling of `ids`. Right now, I have a JSON file which I would like to put into a MongoDB Database. The file looks like this, roughly:

```
{
 id: 'HARRYPOTTER-1',
 title: 'Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone',
 price: 10
}
```

I would now like to put this file into MongoDB. Will my `id` attribute get lost? Will MongoDB want to overwrite it with its own unique id?

I have made sure that my id attributes are unique and I am making use of them elsewhere, so I am a little worried now. But maybe I understood things incorrectly.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Mongodb **creates** an `_id` field any element that doesn't have it.
2. If `_id` already there, it won't overwrite it. (and throws an error instead).
3. If `id` is there, mongodb doesn't care. It won't modify, and will follow 1 and 2.

Let's run an example in the mongo shell:

```
    > db.random.insert({
    ...  id: 'HARRYPOTTER-1',
    ...  title: 'Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone',
    ...  price: 10
    ... })
    WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

And now inspect the inserted document

```
 > db.random.findOne()
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f954cc93b09d63a06f7a4a9"),
        "id" : "HARRYPOTTER-1",
        "title" : "Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone",
        "price" : 10
    }
```

You can see the `_id` has been created. It doesn't matter `id` and is not overwritten.

---

PS: The right binary you should look for to put that json in a MongoDB database is `mongoimport` (not `mongorestore`).

**For more details refer to the docs.**